# dlopen C++ lib from C and then using std::string with function

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, string

So I successfully used dlload in my C code to get a handle to a library written i C++ in Android and
then I use 
`dlsym(handle_from_dlload, "function name as string");`
for the constructor

Then I can just use this constructor by calling my own typedef'ed MyCreate, no problems works very well. e.g.
`void* myhandle = malloc(16);
MyCreate(myhandle, 1);`

this is defined in my C code like this
`typedef void (*MyCreate)(void *handle, uint32_t nbr)`
and having this signature in C++
`OtherClassInLib::OtherClassInLib(uint32_t nbr)`

But there is also a constructor that takes a C++ `std::string`

That I have declared like this in my C code
`typedef void (*MyCreate2)(void *handle, uint32_t nbr, void* isVoidStarCorrectHere)`
that has this signature in C++
`OtherClassInLib::OtherClassInLib(uint32_t nbr, std::string astring)`

How do I call this constructor with a string e.g. "hello" from C as the string is an object?
I have tried various ways like just a char* or char[] and malloced memory for this but always the same, a crash?

I appear to not have access to #include  and the constructor/function with the std::string has successfully been loaded with dlsym.
My C++ is really rusty so I would appreciate some help understanding this.

Comment: I am honestly surprised any of this works at all. Is there any reason you can't use `C++`?

Comment: It works very well in fact and I'm not the first to do something like this. The reason for not using C++ is that I don't really have access to headers (hence the dlload), there is a build system in place for the C code and secondly my C++ is rusty

Comment: Calling C++ from C is UB: on some platforms, it might work in the simplest cases. (Nonetheless, usign dlsym/dlopen neither required nor useful in this.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to write a wrapper in C++ which is the sensible and correct way. The reason that I could not get any C++ headers in like `<string>` was basically that I had not put stl "stlport_static" in gradle

When this worked it was easy to declare the signature correctly using std::string and making the code execute properly.